# Eclipse emulator isn't running up to date version of android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

I'm using eclipse, and my app is at a point where there is a background, and when I run the emulator it doesn't have the background. It had done this before where I changed some text, but when I ran the emulator the text stayed the same. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong then that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that changes made to xml files sometimes do not show up unless you do Project > Clean...

Answer (score 0):

i tried the layout it works fine. You create a folder named as drawable similar to drawable-hdpi. Put your image inside the  drawable folder. It work fine.

or

> Blockquote

Another option about the problem is that you created you Emulator in such a way that the Android OS determines its screen as xhdpi. If an image is placed in drawable resource folder then Android will try to rescale it for the different resolutions. However if the image appears only in some of the resolution folders (lie drawable-ldpi etc) then the image will be served only in this resolutions.

Please, either create folder drawable-xhdpi and place the image also there, or create folder drawable and place the image there. It will be used for backup.

See the documentation about the image folders: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html